# Dart/Flutter: build_value vs json_serializable

Tags: json, serialization, dart, flutter

Wondering what is the different between the dart libraries [build_value](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value) vs [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) ?

both appears to be doing the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-using-code-generation-libraries) mentions:

> The `json_serializable` package allows you to make regular classes serializable by using annotations,
> whereas the `built_value` package provides a higher-level way of defining immutable value classes
> that can also be serialized to JSON.